# Why can't I reuse "unapply" without repeating the method signature

Tags: scala, extractor, unapply

The following Scala code compiles fine:

```
val f = (input: String) => Some("result")
object Extract {
   def unapply(input: String): Option[String] = f(input)
}
val Extract(result) = "a string"
```

But if I replace the extractor by:

```
object Extract {
   def unapply = f
}
```

Then compilation fails with:

```
error: an unapply result must have a member `def isEmpty: Boolean
val Extract(result) = "a string"
    ^
```

Why? Where does `def isEmpty: Boolean` come from?

Comment: I suppose, some of us just love nesting ... What if it is `Seq[Seq[Seq[Seq[Seq[Int]]]]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala 2.10 (and before) `unapply` had to always return an `Option` or a `Boolean`. Since 2.11, it can return any type, so far as it has `def isEmpty: Boolean` and `def get: <some type>` methods (like `Option` does). See https://hseeberger.wordpress.com/2013/10/04/name-based-extractors-in-scala-2-11/ for an explanation why it's useful.
But your `unapply` returns a `String => Some[String]`, which doesn't have either, and that's what the error says.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question - `isEmpty` comes from internals of `Option` type.

`def unapply = f` means - create a parameterless method that returns a function. This is not a method by itself and thus you have an error.

You can further read about difference between function and method in Scala there: [Difference between method and function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala)

Comment: "This is not a method by itself" What do you mean? `unapply` is; `f` isn't, but it isn't relevant.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I meant unapply in this scenario is not a method with f signature. it's a method that returns a function